# Setting 'flags' in Pine Script to buy and hold

Tags: pine-script

I'm having a hard time wraping my head around this language.

I want to setup some variables that that dont change every bar, so that I can later change them in if/elses statements.

eg:

```
f(x) => math.ceil(x / 500) * 500
g(x) => math.floor(x / 500) * 500

if bar_index == 0 
    start_price = g(close / 1.15)
    end_price = f(close)
else:
    if close <= start_price 
        strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, 100)
        strategy.exit('Long', when=end_price)
        start_price = g(close - 500)
        end_price = f(start_price*1.15)
```

But ofcourse I can't do that because start_price and end_price are Undeclared. But if I declare them outside the if statement, they will change every new bar and the condition `close <= start_price` will never be met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `var` keyword when declaring them, to avoid them changing at every bar.

Please read the [Variable declarations](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#) chapter in the [Pine Script 5 User Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html).
Also take a look at [What’s the difference between ==, = and :=?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#whats-the-difference-between---and-) at [PineCoders](https://www.pinecoders.com/).
This will make things more clear.

Your amended example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Script", overlay=false)

var float   start_price = na
var float   end_price   = na

f(x) => math.ceil(x / 500) * 500
g(x) => math.floor(x / 500) * 500

if bar_index == 0 
    start_price := g(close / 1.15)
    end_price   := f(close)
else
    if close <= start_price 
        strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, 100)
        strategy.exit('Long', limit=end_price)
        start_price := g(close - 500)
        end_price   := f(start_price*1.15)

plot(na)
```